# edittext iOS style

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to make a survey for Android. I have a wireframe which I will post below. I am wondering how to make these boxes the same as they are on the screenshot. Please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvMoP.png)

Comment: 9patch image. By the way, that is not an edittext.

Comment: @AmanGrover what is this then?

Comment: told you, a 9patch image on a `TextView` or a `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You seem new to android, You can do this by 9patch image.

9 Patch images are stretchable, repeatable images reduced to their smallest size. The simplest example would be if you were to take a rounded div and slice it up into 9 squares like you would a tic-tac-toe board. The four corners wouldn't change sizes at all but would be static while the other 5 pieces would be stretched or repeated to allow the whole image to scale appropriately.

You can make your 9patch image by using this link

> https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example

or i can give you similer image if you like to use

[image]

[image]